# Why isn't my array sorting properly?

Tags: php

This is the "months" array before the sorting:

```
array(3) { [2011]=> array(3) { [12]=> string(2) "12" ["04"]=> string(2) "04" ["01"]=> string(2) "01" } [2013]=> array(1) { [10]=> string(2) "10" } [2010]=> array(1) { ["05"]=> string(2) "05" } }
```

And here's the "months" array after the sorting:

```
array(3) { [2011]=> array(3) { [12]=> string(2) "12" ["04"]=> string(2) "04" ["01"]=> string(2) "01" } [2010]=> array(1) { ["05"]=> string(2) "05" } [2013]=> array(1) { [10]=> string(2) "10" } }
```

Here is my code:

```
    var_dump($months);
    foreach($months as $year => $month_array)
    {
      arsort($months[$year]);
    }

    arsort($days);
    arsort($months);
    arsort($years);
    var_dump($months);
```

I would like it to produce the years in reverse order (2013, 2011, 2010)

Comment: use **ksort()** for revers order **krsort()**

Comment: What is the meaning of saving (12 => '12', '04' => '04')? Seems you are storing unrequired data. Why no using `('12', '04', ..)` - meaning a numeric array?

Comment: I'm confused on what your code is even trying to achieve. Some context would be nice. Show us a `var_dump($years)` before and after your `arsort()` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [ksort](https://www.php.net/ksort) for Sorting an array by key.

```
$a =  array(
        2001 => '2001',
        2004 => '2004',
        2009 => '2009',
);
ksort($a);
print_r($a);

output:

Array ( [2001] => 2001 [2004] => 2004 [2009] => 2009 )
```

use [krsort](https://www.php.net/krsort) for revers order (**This is what you need**).

```
$a =  array(
        2001 => '2001',
        2004 => '2004',
        2009 => '2009',
);
krsort($a);
print_r($a);

output:

Array ( [2009] => 2009 [2004] => 2004 [2001] => 2001 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using arsort in the wrong place it should be outside the `foreach`

```
arsort($months);

foreach($months as $key => $value)
{
echo $key . '=>' .$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sort your array by DESC and by Keys. 
Use

```
krsort($array);
```

And start using php.net search. It's very handy thing to avoid wasting time

Answer (score 0):

To get the years in reverse order, you should put the array keys (in your case the years) in a seperate array, and finally reverse sort them:

```
$years = array_keys( $months ); // => array( 2011, 2010, 2013 )
rsort( $years );
var_dump( $years ); // => array( 2013, 2011, 2010 )
```

If you want the entire array to be sorted by years, try **krsort**:

```
krsort( $months );
var_dump( $months ); // => array( 2013 => array( ... ), 2011 => array( ... ), 2010 => array( ... ) );
```

Also see:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php